# why the HTML is not taking the value from hidden discription field from HTML to salesforce?

Tags: web2lead

[image]written the below code and the description field is not taking the value in salesforce.

```
Country:<select  id="00N370000073Itq" name="00N370000073Itq" title="Country">
<option value="">--None--</option><option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
<option value="Japan">Japan</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
<option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
<option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
<option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
<option value="Dubai">Dubai</option>
<option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
<option value="France">France</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Italy">Italy</option>
<option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
<option value="Russia">Russia</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
<option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
</select><br>

Message:<textarea  id="00N37000006itEA" name="00N37000006itEA" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>

<input type=hidden name="Description" id="Description" value="CNT_2017_01_01_FR_CartoonSeries">

<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: Post the original code instead of image .

Comment: Country:<select  id="00N370000073Itq" name="00N370000073Itq" title="Country"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
</select><br>

Message:<textarea  id="00N37000006itEA" name="00N37000006itEA" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>

<input type=hidden name="Description" id="Description" value="CNT_2017_01_01_FR_CartoonSeries">. i tried entering that code but that is taking that as HTML and not showing anything this is my code. i have reduced it by removing the picklist options

Comment: Update code in question .

Comment: <input type=hidden name="Description" id="Description" value="CNT_2017_01_01_FR_CartoonSeries"> this is the right syntax for hidden field ?

Comment: what you wanted to achieve from this ? You wanted pass the selected value from visual force to apex ?

Comment: You have shared a Full html code in that .

Comment: i want the hidden value CNT_2017_01_01_FR_CartoonSeries to pass from our website to salesforce. we are using web to lead feature. Description is the standard lead field in salesforce.

Comment: salesforce Api you have  to create .

Comment: please share an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Salesforce docs

> Note: When writing the name/id of the field, use only lowercase, even
>   though the API name shows capitalised in Salesforce

So instead of `Description` change it into `description` and it will work.

[How do I use hidden parameters in Web to Case and Web to Lead?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005680&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

A **Force.com** Site allows for **unauthenticated** access. All access is done via a special "**Site Guest User**" user that has a dedicated profile that you add your page to.

Write an Apex class annotated with **@RestResource** that has an **@HttpPost** method. That method would need to receive data into an SObject and insert that SObject for use by other parts of your application. The class must be added to the dedicated profile.